# pool.apply_async only has one process

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

I wrote a code for data cleaning. The operating func is "single_worker", assigning values from "a" to "l" if the first column is greater than the cutoff points. Since the whole dataset is pretty large, I divided it into 8 subsets for this multiprocessing method. However, when I run this code in cmd, it actually has only one process working on subset1 and when this process finishes, there is no further process for the subset2.

My python version is 3.7 with all anaconda packages. The computer system is win10 with 12 cores.

Here is the function:

```
    def single_worker(merge, beme, me,a):
        c = 0
        year_1 = 0
        month_1 = 0
        length = len(merge)
        for i in trange(length):
        c = c + 1
        year = merge['year'][i]
        month = merge['month'][i]
        if (year != year_1) | (month != month_1):
            key_beme = beme[beme.year == year].index.tolist()
            k=key_beme[0]
            beme6 = beme['6'][k]
            beme14 = beme['14'][k]

            key_me = me[(me.year==year)&(me.month==month)].index.tolist()
            b=key_me[0]
            me10 = me['10'][b]

            year_1 = year
            month_1 = month


        if ~(merge['me'][i] > 0):
            merge['bs_new'][i] = np.nan
            continue
        if merge['me'][i] <= me10:
            merge['bs_new'][i] = 's'
        else:
            merge['bs_new'][i] = 'b'

        if ~(merge['bm'][i] > 0):
            merge['hl_new'][i] = np.nan
            continue
        if merge['bm'][i] <= beme6:
            merge['hl_new'][i] = 'l'
        elif merge['bm'][i] >= beme14:
            merge['hl_new'][i] = 'h'
        else:
            merge['hl_new'][i] = 'm'
        name = str(a)+".csv"
        merge.to_csv(name)
```

Here is the code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np


    from tqdm import trange                  
    from multiprocessing import cpu_count    
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from single_worker import single_worker

    merge = pd.read_csv('merge.csv')
    beme = pd.read_csv('beme.csv')
    me = pd.read_csv('me.csv')
    Len_imgs = len(merge)  
    num_cores = cpu_count()  


    if num_cores >= 8:  
    num_cores = 8
    subset1 = merge[:Len_imgs // 8]
    subset2 = merge[Len_imgs // 8: Len_imgs // 4]
    subset3 = merge[Len_imgs // 4: (Len_imgs * 3) // 8]
    subset4 = merge[(Len_imgs * 3) // 8: Len_imgs // 2]
    subset5 = merge[Len_imgs // 2: (Len_imgs * 5) // 8]
    subset6 = merge[(Len_imgs * 5) // 8: (Len_imgs * 6) // 8]
    subset7 = merge[(Len_imgs * 6) // 8: (Len_imgs * 7) // 8]
    subset8 = merge[(Len_imgs * 7) // 8:]

    List_subsets = [subset1, subset2, subset3, subset4,
                    subset5, subset6, subset7, subset8]
    print("Finish separating subsets")
    p = Pool(num_cores)

    k=0

    for i in range(num_cores):
        k=k+1
        p.apply_async(single_worker, (List_subsets[i], beme, me,k,))

        print(k)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

By the way, when it was running, I checked the task manager. The CPU utilization is below 25% all the time. I do not know if it is a problem with my code. Please take a look. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have no idea if this is the cause of your larger issue, but `if ~(merge['me'][i] > 0)` is almost certainly not doing what you want it to do. Bitwise operations are not useful with boolean values, because `~True` is -2, which is still truthy. You probably want `if not (merge['me'][i] > 0)` or `if merge['me'][i] <= 0` (and something similar for the other places you use `~`).

Comment: Is this code complete? When using `multiprocessing` on windows, the code in your script should generally be inside an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, otherwise it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: I forgot to paste that part. In my code, I have this if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I tried not to use trange in the function I defined, and it works. This seems to be weird, and I do not know the reason.